# Keep focus on textarea after button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

Please advice how to keep focus on textarea element after clicking specific button. For my mobile app I use Quasar vue based framework.

Tried to apply preventDefault

```
<q-btn @click.prevent="handleClick" label="click me" />
```

and stopPropagation

```
 <q-btn @click.stop="handleClick" label="click me" />
```

But in any case textarea losses the focus after button click.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/olegef/pen/NWNvxJM

UPD:
workaround with forced focus causes side effects on mobile like blinking embedded keyboard. That is why I'm looking for option with permanent focus.

UPD2:
it works just fine if I use simple div as a button and mousedown event instead of click

Comment: That's because the button now has focus. Your button click handler should call `texara.focus()`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl in case of mobile application it causes blinking of embedded keyboard.  Is there a way to avoid it using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. Polywhirl mentioned in the comments, that's because after click, the button has the focus. One way to return the focus to the input is like this:

Add `ref` attribute to your input:

```
ref="myInput"
```

So your `input` becomes:

```
<q-input
  ref="myInput"
  v-model="text"
  filled
  type="textarea"
>
</q-input>
```

Then in the `handleClick` method add this line:

```
this.$refs.myInput.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question author left the update "it works just fine if I use simple div as a button and mousedown event instead of click". In fact, the desired effect can be achieved using a button element. Here the `mousedown` event is prevented, to stop focus being lost from the text area, while the click handler is invoked as normal:

```js
<q-btn @mousedown.prevent @click="handleClick" label="click me"></q-btn>
```

This can be seen in [this forked codepen](https://codepen.io/stevemjohns/pen/OJjQwKE). (The second button has the above fix.)